# python27 post requests fails

Tags: python, python-requests

I used this code to log-in to `baiscopelk.com`

- In Python 3.6, `print(res_1) == <Response [302]>`
- but in Python 2.7 I get `print(res_1) == <Response [403]>`

I can't understand the problem

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Origin': 'https://www.baiscopelk.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKi'
                  't/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.baiscopelk.com/wp-login.php',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'si,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8',
}

data = {
  'log': 'baiscopelk.username',
  'pwd': 'baiscopelk.password',
  'wp-submit': 'Log In',
  'redirect_to': 'https://www.baiscopelk.com/wp-admin/',
  'testcookie': '1'
}
res_0 = requests.get('https://www.baiscopelk.com/wp-login.php', headers=headers)
res_1 = requests.post('https://www.baiscopelk.com/wp-login.php', headers=headers, data=data, cookies=res_0.cookies,
                      allow_redirects=False)

print(res_1)
```

Comment: have you tried using `json.dumps(data)` instead of just `data` in `requests.post`?

Comment: yes. <Response [403]>

Comment: It is so strange, i make a same request by py2x and py3x but 2x still returns 403 3x returns 302. The difference is the order of param or encode

Comment: Also i have checked the difference on requests's files, but no difference(i copied py3x module's files to py2x folder but it still responds 403)!

Comment: I even build a simple post function by urllib3, and still gets same result. It seems a very difficult question, because it may associate with standard library.

Comment: site has been changed. now it's working on both. thanks